# Why is the content in a modal dialog being truncated?

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I'm following along a book tutorial and I've hit a problem that I can't solve. Hopefully somebody here can help.

There is essentially a modal dialog - wizard dialog - with dynamic pl/sql content, which is being truncated for some reason.  I'm wondering if this is normal behaviour:

[image: truncated modal dialog window]

The db is sending more than those 3 rows displayed in the Product/Price table. If I hack the code to stop rendering rows after one row:

[image]

Is this something that's easily explainable?  The code that's building all this stuff is this; I don't expect anyone to read it in detail, but I'm just left wondering if a browser is supposed to automatically insert a vertical scrollbar:

[original lengthy code removed]

Thanks

Edit:
I've removed inline CSS on the page, and reduced the dynamic PL/SQL to this, but it's still happening:

```
declare
  l_customer_id varchar2(30) := :P11_CUSTOMER_ID;
begin
    -- display products
    sys.htp.p('<div class="Products" >');
    sys.htp.p('<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <thead>
    <tr><th class="left">Product</th><th>Price</th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>');
    for c1 in (select product_id, product_name,  list_price, 'Add to Cart' add_to_order from demo_product_info where product_avail = 'Y' union all 
               select product_id, product_name,  list_price, 'Add to Cart' add_to_order from demo_product_info where product_avail = 'Y'order by product_name) loop
        sys.htp.p('<tr><td class="left">'||sys.htf.escape_sc(c1.product_name)||'</td>
        <td>'||trim(to_char(c1.list_price,'999G999G990D00')) || '</td>
        <td><a ><span>Add<i class="iR"></i></span></a></td>
        </tr>');
    end loop;
    sys.htp.p('</tbody></table>');
    sys.htp.p('</div>');
    sys.htp.p('<b>DONE</b>');
end;
```

There are 11 rows returned by the sql query; I've doubled them up to 22 so there should be 22 rows in the resulting table, but this is the output:

[image]

I don't know if it helps, but...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set a height for your modal page in page settings?

Try to put this css in your page settings:

*Change this number (400) by the height of your modal or something close to that.

```
.CustomerInfo {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto !important;
}
```

---

I don't know why this happen, I think this issue is related of this property https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

---

**EDIT**

I created this page to test: page 25 is the modal page, page 23 have a link to the modal page.

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:23

Login on: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1

```
workspace: stackquestions
user: test
pwd: test
app: 145797
wizard modal page: 25
```

Could check if is there any diference in the page settings or in the region settings between your modal page and this page above? or could you try to replicate this problem in this workspace?

The wizard modal page have a region with this pl/sql, the same of yours, but with fake data.

```
declare

  v_count NUMBER := 0;
  v_max_count NUMBER := 30;
begin
    -- display products
    sys.htp.p('<div class="Products" >');
    sys.htp.p('<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <thead>
    <tr><th class="left">Product</th><th>Price</th><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>');
    loop
        sys.htp.p('<tr><td class="left">'||'product - ' || v_count ||'</td>
        <td>'|| '50 - ' || v_count || '</td>
        <td><a ><span>Add<i class="iR"></i></span></a></td>
        </tr>');

    v_count := v_count + 1;

    EXIT WHEN v_count >= v_max_count; 

    end loop;

    sys.htp.p('</tbody></table>');
    sys.htp.p('</div>');
    sys.htp.p('<b>DONE</b>');
end;
```

Comment: Hi, yes, there was a height (and width) specified, as per my book, but removing them makes no difference. Thanks for the pointer to overflow; I had been, and have been playing with this but still I cannot make the content show. It's maddening.

Comment: Sorry I realy don't know what is the problem, could you past the HTML generated by this pl/sql in your question? I created a page to test this issue here and the modal page have the bar to scroll the content. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:23

Comment: No need to apologise. I appreciate the help. I'm not sure though how I can provide the html: as you'd expect it's a labyrinthine mess of css and html.  I can right click on the modal dialog and select "view source"; would that help?

Comment: The apex modal pages show the scroll bar to show the content when needed. The problem seems to be some CSS statement, some absolute or fixed position ... The only way to know would be checking the html and css statements ... What are the css instructions for the class "Products"?

Comment: There was inline CSS on the page, but I've removed it, so there is no longer any CSS on Products; it has affected the presentation as you'd expect (the screenshot is above after my edit) but the truncation issue remains. All I have is a modal page that uses a wizard modal template, and a small amount of PL/SQL that generates a few rows. I am running 5.1.4.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was so kind of you to go to that effort, and what I saw as soon as I looked at your code was that you hadn't created the modal dialog as a sub-region of the progress bar. I have no idea why, but the instructions in my workbook said to create the modal dialog as a sub-region of the progress bar; it never occurred to me that this would have caused the behaviour that it did. I have just put everything back in as per the original instructions, except that the dialog is a separate region below the progress bar, and it all works perfectly. Again, many many thanks.